# Finding TFS project portals after a restore and upgrade

Tags: tfs, import

We're trying to work on an upgrade from TFS 2010 to 2012. We have all new hardware for the new servers and so we went with a migration and upgrade. Our SharePoint server is configured with TFS extensions. The TFS 2012 installation went well and TFSRestore worked without error and TFSConfig import worked without error. All of the project portal sites (ex. https://projects.example.com/sites/MyProject) are available and navigable by URL.

We can browse to projects in Team Explorer and go to to http://tfs.example.com:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection/MyProject. But there's no "Go to project portal" link in the project site, and the project's portal settings don't have a url listed there.

Question 1: Are my project portal settings really gone?

Question 2: Is there a way to restore these programmatically?

Comment: Does the sharepoint site appear in TFS Administration Console?

Comment: Yes, it's listed there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We found out some interesting things over the past day. The Upgrade Guidance from the ALM Rangers seemed to indicate that SQL Server 2005 couldn't be used in an in-place upgrade, so we went with the manual backup/restore/tfsconfig import I mentioned in the question.

One of our DBAs looked at the 2005 databases and asked, "why not just migrate these to 2008 R2 and run the Upgrade option from the TFS installer?" We went through this and the wizard converted all our projects and maintained their portal URL without issue.